# How to Create A Simple Module display all Product in Magento

Tags: magento

Im studying Magento, but i cant find tutorials or documents about create a new module display all Product. 
Someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module Creation Tutorial : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table

To display all products, in your PHTML file write below code:

```
echo "<pre>";
$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach($productCollection as $product) {
   print_r($product->getData()); //You can display it in tabular structure       
}
echo "</pre>";
```

Hope this helps !!